# Silverlight MVVM classes represented in UML diagrams

Tags: mvvm, silverlight-4.0, uml

For a typical Silverlight MVVM styled project, how are the classes involved expressed in UML? All I have are the View.xaml, the View.xaml.cs and the viewmodel. The Viewmodel inherits from a ViewModelBase class. This ViewModelBase class which implements Inotifyfproperty is available thru a dll reference to the current Silverlight project.
Should the classes in that dll be also mentioned in my UML diagram?

All I want to do is show a class diagram depicting generalization and association.

I hope I have articulated this question properly. Thanks for your time..

Answer (score 1):

A nice way to 'solve' this is by first documenting the MVVM pattern on an abstract level. After that you could use the pattern in your class diagram.

[See this documentation of Enterprise Architect how they do it](http://www.sparxsystems.com/resources/developers/uml_patterns.html)

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are concerned only for associations for your bussiness logic there is no need to specify external classes. However you can show it in the package diagram.